# How to add same id objects into each others in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to combine objects with each others if they are same id.

```
let obj = 
         [ 
           {id: 1, users: '1,2,3'},
           {id: 1, users: '4,5,6'},
           {id: 2, users: '1,2'},
           {id: 2, users: '3'}
         ]

and I would like to get combined objects with same id.

[ 
  {id: 1, users: '1,2,3,4,5,6'},
  {id: 2, users: '1,2,3'}
]
```

Comment: Can you share with us your attempts to solve this?  We are happy to help you get your solution working.

Comment: Hi Amy, thank you for your respond I am new in javascript, but anyway I tried to use nested for loops and compare two id with each others if same push to object, somehow it is not working

Comment: It's easier to help you when we can see your code :)  Please edit your question with your solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let obj = 
         [ 
           {id: 1, users: '1,2,3'},
           {id: 1, users: '4,5,6'},
           {id: 2, users: '1,2'},
           {id: 2, users: '3'},
           {id: 3, users: '3,2,4'},
           {id: 3, users: '5,1,2'}
         ];
         
const mergeSameIds = obj => (
  obj.reduce( (res, o) => {
    res[o.id] = {
      id: o.id,
      users: !res[o.id] ? o.users : [...new Set(res[o.id].users.split(',').concat(o.users.split(',')))].sort().join(',')
    }
    
    return res;
  }, {} )
  
);

console.log(mergeSameIds(obj));
```

here is a more advance solution. This one removes duplicates and also sorts the users